# jQuery UI tutorial/example/sample

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

i'm finding it tough to understand some of the Jquery UI tutorials, as they are way too descriptive for my liking,

so what I want is

1) style the drop-down that appears on this auto-complete textbox

```
                      OR/AND
```

2) give some good links to jQuery UI dev

```
                      OR/AND
```

3) give an example on styling the autocomplete box.

auto-complete on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfkt4/8/)
please share some code on how to style it like [this](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Links to download sites will also be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

this is a good resource too:

http://choosedaily.com/1308/15-jquery-autocomplete-plugins-tutorials/

**Updated**

To style the resulting UL > LI as the example you have to:

1. set the right font
2. set a background image on li:hover
3. set rounded corners like this: border-radius:
   4px 4px 4px 4px;

You can always download the jQuery css and apply it 
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/css/parseTheme.css.php?ctl=themeroller

Comment: again, I want some code on how to style it, this link has generic code under style, or if you can guide me on that page, would be great